# Copying an ArrayList of a Subclass to an ArrayList of a Superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

I have a superclass and two subclasses that extend that superclass.

I have an ArrayList that holds some objects of the first subclass, and another ArrayList that holds some objects of the second subclass.

I want to copy the references from one of those ArrayLists of subclass objects into an ArrayList of the superclass objects, because this saves a lot of lines of codes (having only one list instead of two).

```
ArrayList<SubClass1> listOfSubClass1Objects = getList1();
ArrayList<SubClass2> listOfSubClass2Objects = getList2();

ArrayList<SuperClass> listOfSuperClassObjects = new ArrayList<SuperClass>();

if (needsSubClass1){
    listOfSuperClassObjects = listOfSubClass1Objects;
} else {
    listOfSuperClassObjects = listOfSubClass2Objects;
}
```

This gives the Error: `Cannot convert from ArrayList<SubClass1> to ArrayList<SuperClass>`

So what I can do is make a for loop: For each object, add to the `listOfSuperClassObjects`. But it seems like a hassle to me and I was wondering if there is a shorter way.

**Q: How can I easily cast a list of a type of object to a list of the superclass of that type of object?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implements the [`Collection` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and therefore supports the [`Collection.addAll()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
if (needsSubClass1) {
    listOfSuperClassObjects.addAll(listOfSubClass1Objects);
} else {
    listOfSuperClassObjects.addAll(listOfSubClass2Objects);
}
```

Incidentally, `ArrayList` also has a [generic copy constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) that probably just calls `addAll()` on its own:

```
listOfSuperClassObjects = new ArrayList<SuperClass>(listOfSubClass1Objects);
```

Comment: Quick and easy, exactly what I was looking for :)